# Cant save customer attributes in Cron Job observer!

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have setup a cronjob in my custom module and it works fine. I know this because i put a PHP email script in there and I do in fact receive the email. The problem is with loading the customer model. It won't load the customer, much less save a customer attribute.

A few things: 
1. Yes entity_id 50 does absolutely exist. 
2. When I leave the first 3 lines in pendingApproval() I do not get the email. When i remove them I do get the email.
3. I have tried changing the email, firstname, lastname. Nothing. But this same code works when I run it in a controller in my browser.

Do i have the wrong current store or what? It's strange because I have another method in the same observer.php file and I make a call to the getModel('customer/customer') and it allows me to retrieve and save. However, it does not utilize a cronjob.

Any help is appreciated. Been messing with this for hours.

```
    <crontab>
    <jobs>
        <mycompany_referral>
            <schedule><cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>referral/observer::pendingApproval</model></run>
        </mycompany_referral>   
    </jobs>
</crontab>  


<?php

class MyCompany_Referral_Model_Observer {

public function pendingApproval() {

    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(50);
    $customer->setEmail('joebob@yahoo.com');
    $customer->save();

    $to      = 'myemail@email.com';
    $subject = 'alex';
    $message = 'ljoe';
    $headers = 'From: myemail@email.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: myemail@email.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);  

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing I can suggest is to enable logging to see what is going on. Or you can wrap the save set of code in a try catch block so you can see if there is an exception being thrown.

```
try {
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(50);
    $customer->setEmail('joebob@yahoo.com');
    $customer->save();
} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    Do something here with $e
}
```

You could also try calling `validate` on the customer object before calling `save`

Comment: Wow thanks for much for your comment. Simply wrapping it in a try catch fixed it. No error existed.